# flutter_animarker can't turn ripple animation off

Tags: flutter, google-maps, animation

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker

Wow, this is annoying.  So `Animarker` is a Widget parent for my Google map.  The map is busy with Markers.  When the user needs to find a particular Marker from the drawer, they tap the item & it triggers a Ripple effect in the corresponding Marker.

The problem is it never stops rippling.  It'll even attempt to animate several Markers if the user keeps on tapping.

It was love at first animation but I'm climbing the walls now!

```
Animarker(
      isActiveTrip: rippleAnimationActive,
      rippleRadius: 0.5,  //[0,1.0] range, how big is the circle
      rippleColor: Colors.teal, // Color of fade ripple circle
      rippleDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500), //Pulse ripple duration
      markers: animatedMarkerSet,

      mapId: _mapController.future.then<int>((value) => value.mapId),
      child: GoogleMap(
      key: Key("myGoogleMap"),
      mapType: MapType.hybrid,
      initialCameraPosition: _edinburghCamera,
      markers: _markers,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _mapController.complete(controller);
      },
    ),
    ),
```

I trigger the animation in a Drawer item onTap():

```
                        onTap: () {
                      animatedMarkerSet = {
                        RippleMarker(
                            markerId: MarkerId(presentLocation.name),
                            position: presentLocation.latLng,
                            ripple: true) };

                      setState(() {
                        presentLocation = _location;
                        animatedMarkerSet;
                        rippleAnimationActive = true;
                      });
                      //setState(() => _markers.add(marker));
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
```

You can see I've created a brand new Marker to animate, and added it to the animatedMarkerSet.  This works fine.

When the user taps a Marker, any Marker, details about the location slide up.  And I try to deactivate *ANY* Marker which is rippling.  However no matter what I try it doesn't stop:

```
    setState(() {
  rippleAnimationActive = false;
  animatedMarkerSet.clear(); // nuke from orbit
}
```

I've also tried changing the animatedMarkerSet to a Map, and attempting to deactivate the ripple using this:

```
  void newLocationUpdate(LocationDetails oldLocation) {
var marker = RippleMarker(
  markerId: MarkerId(oldLocation.name),
  position: oldLocation.latLng,
  ripple: false,
);
setState(() => animatedMarkerMap[MarkerId(oldLocation.name)] = marker);
  }
```

But that doesn't work either.

I really really just need to switch the animation on and off.  I don't see why Animarker's so resistant to `setState()`, telling it to stop.

In fact, the best thing might be to just have it run for 5 seconds then switch off, in all circumstances, but I fail to see how to do that either.  Grrrr!

Comment: I'm unclear why it's downvoted.  I'm not the only person with this problem, there are 2 others feeding back to the plugin dev.  My problem however may be caused by lack of insight so help is welcomed.  It beggars belief you can't switch the ripple animation off.  So you probably can.... somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK well I figured it out.  AniMarker which takes the Set of animated Markers, is final.  So once you hand it the set of say RippleMarkers, it'll animate them, but you can't then turn it off via a `SetState()` call.

I tried editing the AniMarker class, to make it not final, so you could mutate it's dataset, but I think because it's built on GoogleMap's Marker class, and they're final, it just will not work.

So AniMarker presently has limited utility.

My work around was just to mutate GoogleMaps `marker:` option, so I could highlight a Marker by changing it's color.  It's also possible to change the `circles:` GoogleMap option to dyanically highlight a Marker according to user interaction.